# Eclipse PDT : obtaining the source code behind an ASTNode

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

I'm exploring the PDT SDK in order to exploit it for an Eclipse plugin I'm writing.

The problem I'm having is this: with a class that extends `org.eclipse.php.internal.core.ast.visitor.AbstractVisitor`, I can find a function with a given name. This returns me an object of type `FunctionDeclaration`.

Is there any way from a `FunctionDeclaration` (or `FunctionDeclaration.getAST()`) to have back the source code that is behind the AST itself?

Using `FunctionDeclaration.toString()` I can only obtain an XML-like representation of the tree, that is not what I whish.

Many thanks in advance, this problem is driving me crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
import org.eclipse.php.internal.core.ast.rewrite.ASTRewriteFlattener;
...
String functionSource = ASTRewriteFlattener.asString(foundAction, new RewriteEventStore());
```

sorry i didn't find the `ASTRewriteFlattener` class before adding the above question. I leave the answer here for the record.